# How do I develop for Xperia X10 on Android 2.1 when the SDK addon only supports Android 1.6

Tags: android-emulator

I have installed android tools and eclipse successfully (making the hello World and hello widget examples) and have run these successfully on the Xperia X10 add-on that I downloaded from the developer site of SE.

However, my phone is running the updated Android 2.1, and any apps that I make will either have to run on 1.6, or will not be able to be tested on the Xperia X10 during development without moving it to my physical phone.

I have contacted Sony and they told me there is no add-on with 2.1 on it. And that is all they would say.

My Question:

Is there anyone out there who has developed for this phone, who knows what to do? Do I somehow run the SE update tool on the virtual phone to upgrade the OS of the image? Or am I missing something much more obvious?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the adb for getting your phone in debug mode.

Or you can just install your APKs via OTA or via USB in your physical phone.

Or you could just develop on 2.1 knowing that almost everything will work. I don't get the problem, really.

Comment: I have a very old laptop that won't let me run apps on my phone straight from eclipse, I can only use the virtual phone to run it. I will just run it on 2.1 and know that I will run virtually everything. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[As of April 2011](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_%28operating_system%29#Usage_share), this is (an estimate of) Android usage share:

[image: usage pie chart]

That's 3.5% for Android 1.6 and 2.7% for Android 1.5. As time goes by, those percentages will **only** decrease.

#### Just develop for 2.1.

Why do you prefer to use the emulator, anyway? Most Android devs (myself included) have found that the emulator is painfully slow, and it's just plain easier to plug in a real phone and test on that.